# Align bullet with first line of a wrapped TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create a bulleted list in Android where the bullet is aligned to the vertical center of the first line in a TextView like so:

[image]

The XML for a single bullet/text row is this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/setup_intro_bullet_first_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setup_intro_bullet_first"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bullet"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setup_intro_bullet_first_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/setup_intro_benefit_notification"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/setup_intro_bullet_first"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here I use padding on the TextView to align with the bullet, but this is not a solution because the alignment isn't consistent across other resolutions. I've also tried putting the bullet character in the text string itself but then the second line of text will sit under the bullet, which is not what I want. I'd like some advice on how to accomplish this.

Comment: what do you mean by `second line of text will sit under the bullet`?

Comment: I'd use a **compound drawable**, which will stay separate from the text. It's kinda an "ImageView inside a TextView", if it makes sense.

Comment: I don't think that a compound drawable works in this situation, since it would be vertically centered inside the entire view if text wrapped to more than one line, and it sounds like the OP wants it to always align with the center o the top line of text.

Comment: It could be nice, to have it always vertically centered.

Comment: @AshishRanjan I mean if the text wraps to a second line, text from the second line will start directly under the dot, which I don't want. In the screenshot you can see the second line doesn't start under the dot, it is in aligned with the first line of text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to create a circle `Drawable` and use it in an `ImageView`. You can define the baseline of an `ImageView` which allowed me to properly align it with the baseline of the `TextView`. Here is the circle XML:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

And the layout XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/setup_intro_bullet_first"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:baseline="7dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/setup_intro_bullet_first_text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/setup_intro_bullet_first_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/setup_intro_bullet_first_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:text="@string/setup_intro_benefit_notification"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/setup_intro_bullet_first"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: One additional attribute I needed to add for my case was `baselineAlignBottom="true"` in order to get the baseline for the ImageView to be set on the bottom of the view instead of the top.

Comment: Can someone attach a screenshot of the fix? I'd love to see it to know if this is the fix I need.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf` attribute to constrain your "bullet" view's baseline to the baseline of your text view.

Constraints for your bullet view:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/setup_intro_bullet_first_text"
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/setup_intro_bullet_first_text"
```

And for your text:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/setup_intro_bullet_first"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: Constraining the baseline was a good idea but I don't think that works here. The bullet character floats significantly above its own baseline. https://i.imgur.com/cHhLN4u.png

Comment: @JakeMoritz perhaps you could use a different character... one that doesn't sit so high up on the line. I don't know what you're using since it's hidden behind the string resource, but maybe the interpunct character (`\u00B7`, or ·) would work?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried multiple other unicode characters for dots but they just didn't line up correctly.

Comment: @JakeMoritz This was bothering me, so I tried copying/pasting your layout into my editor, and it turns out that the problem is the `style` attribute on the bullet `TextView`; delete that style and the bullet won't be so high up vertically. I assume what's happening is that the text size of the bullet view is significantly larger than the text size of the text view, so the bullet is being "pushed" up. You can use the same text size and a `bold` text style to make sure the bullet is reasonably large.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Pie (28) and above you can use BulletSpan directly. For the below version, you can use `DrawableMarginSpan` but with a broken drawable plus bullet sign `"\u2022"`.

```
val yourSpan = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        BulletSpan(
            8.px,
            ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.gray),
            2.px,
        )
    } else {
        DrawableMarginSpan(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_circle)!!, 20)
    }

val yourString = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
   "Just string"
} else {
    "\u2022" + " Just string"
}

yourTextView.text = SpannableStringBuilder(yourString).apply {
                setSpan(
                    yourSpan,
                    startIndex,
                    endIndex,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
            }
```

Code for broken drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/gray"/>
</shape>
```